# log4j gets stuck at a maximum number of 13 files even though the configured limit is 50?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

This is the log4j properties file we are using, could you please explain why the limit for number of files is stuck at 13 instead of 50 as defined in "maxIndex" Property?

```
    # Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,file,stdout

log4j.logger.com.cisco.assurance=DEBUG, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ} %-5p %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/var/log/smeu/AssuranceMS-%i.log.gz
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=/var/log/smeu/AssuranceMS.log
log4j.appender.file.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=204800000
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=50
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

From the API of `org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy`, it is reduced by design to 12 backups plus the current one, so 13 maximum.

You can look at it : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/FixedWindowRollingPolicy.html

Comment: So you mean the problem is here:

log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy

and we have to use a different policy to get 50 files? or is 13 the maximum possible number in any policy? could you suggest a policy?

Comment: I suggest you can write a custom RollingPolicy with your prerequisites, yes.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because large window size is discouraged and the maxIndex is automatically reduced to 12. It is well documented [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/FixedWindowRollingPolicy.html).

> Given that this rollover algorithm requires as many file renaming operations as the window size, large window sizes are discouraged. The current implementation will automatically reduce the window size to 12 when larger values are specified by the user.

Comment: So you mean the problem is here:

log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy

and we have to use a different policy to get 50 files? or is 13 the maximum possible number in any policy? could you suggest a policy?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. I will explore on overriding this behavior but if you could give me some insight as to how does one go about overriding the default "FixedWindowRollingPolicy" class, any files/paths/configurations or links that could help it would be very helpful to me. Thank you again.